# Illegal expression in java code

Tags: java

I am writing this code in Netbeans for a java class, but I am having a few errors and would really appreciate some help. The assignment is:

> Design and implement a stringed musical instrument class using the following guidelines:
>
> Data fields for your instrument should include number of strings, an array of string names representing string names (e.g. E,A,D,G), and boolean fields to determine if the instrument is tuned, and if the instrument is currently playing. You are welcome to add additional data fields if you like.
>
> A constructor method that set the tuned and currently playing fields to false.
>   Other methods
>
> 1. to tune the instrument
> 2. to start the instrument playing, and
> 3. to stop the instrument from playing.
>      Other methods as you see fit (Add at least one unique method).
>
> Create a UML class diagram using a diagram tool (e.g. PPT, Visio) of your choice.  Prepare the diagrams and place them in a word document along with a brief description of each of your classes.
>
> Create Java classes for your instruments. Be sure that your code matches your design specifications and some minimal functionality is included. For example, if you called the violin.play() method, you should at least print that the violin is playing. Similar functionality should be supplied when you stop playing, tune or call any of your methods. For example:

```
 public void playviolin() {
     System.out.println("The violin is now playing.");
 }
```

> Write the output from your Instrument class methods to a text file that a user entered from the command line arguments (e.g. java Mynamep3tst myfilename.txt). This allows your program to accept filenames from the user via a command line argument.
>
> Finally, create a Java test class that simulates using your instrument class.  In your test class be you should at a minimum: a) Construct 10 instances of your instrument, b) tune your instruments, c) Start playing your instrument, d) Call your unique method, and e) Stop playing your instruments.   (Hint: Arrays and Loops will make your job easier and result in more efficient code!)

So here is my code currently:

```
package andrewrubinfinalproject;

/**
 *
 * @author Andy
 */
public class AndrewRubinFinalProject {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
//fields to determine if the instrument is isTuned,
   private boolean isTuned;

   //and if the instrument is currently isPlaying.
   private boolean isPlaying;


   private String name;

   private int numberOfStrings = 4; // number of strings
   private String nameofStringsInInstrument[] = {"E", "C", "D", "A"}; //an array of string names


    //A constructor method that set the isTuned and currently isPlaying fields to false.

    public AndrewRubinFinalProject() {
        this.isTuned = false;
        this.isPlaying = false;
    }



    public String getNameOfInstrument() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setNameOfInstrument(String nameOfInstrument) {
        this.name = nameOfInstrument;
    }


    // Other methods

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return isPlaying;
    }

    public void setPlaying(boolean playing) {
        this.isPlaying = playing;
    }

    public boolean isTuned() {
        return isTuned;
    }

    public void setTuned(boolean isTuned) {
        this.isTuned = isTuned;
    }

    public void startPlayInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is now Playing.");
        isPlaying = true;
    }

    public void stopPlayInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is not Playing anymore.");
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    public void startTuneInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is Tuned.");
        isTuned = true;
    }

    public void stopTuneInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is not Tuned.");
        isTuned = false;
    }  

    public int getNumberOfStrings() {
       return this.numberOfStrings ;
    }

    public String[] getStringNames() {
        return nameofStringsInInstrument;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's like you've put your entire assignment here :) What's your question by the way ?

Comment: +1 for the most meaningless title I ever read on SO!

Comment: *"a few errors"* Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: @StackOverflowException If that had read *"-1 for the most meaningless.."* I might have joined in the up-votes of the comment.  As it is, I find them quite inexplicable.  Are we about to start awarding up-votes for 'crappiest question of the day'? -1 for some balance.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It was more of "this one made me laugh", because most questions on SO are about not working programs, and java was already in the tag, an since the OP had only 1 rep, -1 wouldn't have meant anything to him. I don't think questions of new users, which are downvoted too much encourage them to participate on SO more...

Comment: @StackOverflowException *"I don't think questions of new users, which are downvoted too much encourage them to participate on SO more..."*  (shrugs) If they are that thin-skinned, the community is probably better off without them.  If they can pick themselves up, brush off the dust, learn new things and continue while *using those things they learned*, welcome.  I really don't see how up-voting bad titles helps either them or the community.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It's just that I think that new users are more likely to not ask new questions if their first question is downvoted a dozen times. Of course, "up-voting bad titles" is not how I meant it and I hope you didn't read it like that.

Comment: I have to agree with @AndrewThompson here. To me, the problem is not with the title but with the question itself. He has not at least identified what his problem was and pasted the entire assignment here. If there are minor mistakes we can always suggest edits, but this?

Comment: I thank most of you for your help and advise. I have implemented many of your comments and have successfully finished the project.  I will continue to seek help and advice here in the future (and I will make more descriptive titles in the future).

Comment: You are welcome @user2804173 . Best wishes for your assignment !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your assignment is given to check your OOP concepts. 
See the code below, I've given a little touch to your code.

```
package andrewrubinfinalproject;

/**
 *
 * @author Andy
 */
public class AndrewRubinFinalProject {


   //fields to determine if the instrument is isTuned,
   private boolean isTuned;

   //and if the instrument is currently isPlaying.
   private boolean isPlaying;

   private String name;

   private int numberOfStrings = 4; // number of strings
   private String nameofStringsInInstrument[] = {"E", "C", "D", "A"}; //an array of string names


    //A constructor method that set the isTuned and currently isPlaying fields to false.

    public AndrewRubinFinalProject() {
        this.isTuned = false;
        this.isPlaying = false;
    }



    public String getNameOfInstrument() {
        return this.name;
    }


    public void setNameOfInstrument(String nameOfInstrument) {
        this.name = nameOfInstrument;
    }


    // Other methods

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return this.isPlaying;
    }

    public void setPlaying(boolean playing) {
        this.isPlaying = playing;
    }

    public boolean isTuned() {
        return this.isTuned;
    }

    public void setTuned(boolean isTuned) {
        this.isTuned = isTuned;
    }

    public void startPlayInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is now Playing.");
        this.isPlaying = true;
    }

    public void stopPlayInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is not Playing anymore.");
        this.isPlaying = false;
    }

    public void startTuneInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is Tuned.");
        this.isTuned = true;
    }

    public void stopTuneInstrument() {
        System.out.println("The Instrument is not Tuned.");
        this.isTuned = false;
    }  

    public int getNumberOfStrings() {
       return this.numberOfStrings ;
    }

    public String[] getStringNames() {
        return this.nameofStringsInInstrument;
    }

}
```

The problem is with the positioning of your main method. 
First write a class as in the above code. 
Then in your main method, make an instance of `AndrewRubinFinalProject` class by calling the constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    AndrewRubinFinalProject andrewsObject= new AndrewRubinFinalProject();
   // you can call any method in your class with respect to andrewsObject
   // e.g.
   // andrewsObject.setNameOfInstrument("Violin");
   // String x= andrewsObject.getNameOfInstrument()


}
```

What you must know is that the main method does not necessarily be in the class you are writing. It can be somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close your `main` method. You should insert `}` before you begin to write other methods.

It's a bad habit to use *magic numbers* in your code, such as `private int numberOfStrings = 4;`, what if you change the array? You'll have to change this number too.

Instead, it's better to use `.length` that returns the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make at least 2 classes. One is `Instrument` with all its fields and methods. And another is your main project class that contains `main()` method and created and uses instruments.
The code that you posted will not be compiled as you opened and not closed the `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

When first starting out in Object Oriented Programming, write up a small description of the problem, or at least think about it in terms that have enough detail.

Initially, the nouns should become your classes.  Abstract groups of nouns *might* be good candidates for interfaces, and the verbs should become methods *belonging* to the class that is "closest" to the verb.  By closest, I mean that performing the verb will require more access to the attributes in the class.